# How to reverse an array in Assembly language ARM with Neon Extension efficiently?

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, neon

I am working with some image processing functions where I need to reverse a byte array fastest way possible. If I try to explain my actual function, it will not be appropriate. That's why I am going to simplify the problem criteria.

```
Input Array: 
37 3B 29 32 C5 E3 F3 5E 04 E2 CA B8 A1 1F 64 1D 
E5 6F 7B 2C EA 6A FD 1F A5 6B 8F FA FB 7A F4 2A 
DC 08 6D DB B8 D4 77 5D A2 44 E6 8A 59 9C 7D C2 
8E FB C6 2A F8 EC 96 ED DC F8 00 2D 63 4C A4 F9
Length: 64
Output Array: 
F9 A4 4C 63 2D 00 F8 DC ED 96 EC F8 2A C6 FB 8E 
C2 7D 9C 59 8A E6 44 A2 5D 77 D4 B8 DB 6D 08 DC 
2A F4 7A FB FA 8F 6B A5 1F FD 6A EA 2C 7B 6F E5 
1D 64 1F A1 B8 CA E2 04 5E F3 E3 C5 32 29 3B 37
```

It's really easy to do this job in higher level language like C++. In C++ this implementation might look like:

```
void Reverse_array(unsigned char* pInData, int iLen, unsigned char* pOutData)
{
    int indx = 0;
    for(int i=iLen-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        pOutData[indx++] = pInData[i];
    }
}
```

But I really need to find the most efficient and optimized solution to do this job. As this task is going to execute in mobile devices I decided to implement using raw assembly language in ARM with Neon Extension. Now, I am going to share my effort to implement this task (still this is incomplete).

```
NEON_ASM_FUNC_BEGIN Reverse_array_arm_neon
push {r2-r8, lr}
#r0 First parameter, This is the address of <pInData>
#r1 Second Parameter, This is the iLen
#r2 Third Parameter, This is the address of <pOutData>
add r2, r2, r1
ands r3, r1, #7
add r2, r2, #8

loop_Reverse:
vld1.u8 {d0}, [r0]!
vrev64.u8 d1, d0
sub r2, r2, #16
vst1.u8 {d1}, [r2]!
subs r1, #8
bne loop_Reverse

pop {r2-r8, pc}
NEON_ASM_FUNC_END
```

I have also checked [How to reverse an array in assembly language ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280723/how-to-reverse-an-array-in-assembly-language-arm) and [Reversing an array in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121048/reversing-an-array-in-assembly) solutions from StackOverFlow, but still I need some more knowledge regarding this implementation.

1. **Is it possible to write faster function than c++ in arm assembly language for this problem?**
2. **What will be the proper way to implement this task using the feature of NEON extension? (My function is incomplete, because it's not gonna work in different length which is not divisible by 8).**

Any idea or information will be helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation to me - try benchmarking/profiling `std::reverse` first to see whether this really is a good candidate for optimisation before wasting a lot of time and effort writing non-portable and less robust code which may turn out to be of little or no benefit?

Comment: Do `In` and `out` overlap, or are they even the same?

Comment: Of course, NEON version will be a lot faster if std:reverse isn't optimized for NEON, especially because of the lifted alignment and lower bandwith requirement.

Comment: @RajibTheKing: you might find [this article](https://github.com/Wunkolo/qreverse) useful - it focuses more on x86/SSE/AVX but many of the techniques can be usefully applied to other SIMD architectures, such as NEON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided In and Out don't overlap, and `iLen` is greater than 64, the code below should work:

```
// Written by Jake 'Alquimista' LEE

    .syntax unified
    .arch   armv7-a
    .fpu    neon
    .text
    .global Reverse_array_arm_neon

// void Reverse_array_arm_neon(unsigned char* pInData, int iLen, unsigned char* pOutData);


pSrc    .req    r0
iLen    .req    r1
pDst    .req    r2
postInc .req    r3

.balign 32
.func
Reverse_array_arm_neon:
    add     pDst, pDst, iLen
    mov     postInc, #-32
    sub     pDst, pDst, #32
    sub     iLen, iLen, #64     // "withholding tax"

.balign 32
1:
    vld1.8      {d16, d17, d18, d19}, [pSrc]!
    vld1.8      {d20, d21, d22, d23}, [pSrc]!
    subs    iLen, iLen, #64
    pld [pSrc, #64]

    vrev64.8    q8, q8
    vrev64.8    q9, q9
    vrev64.8    q10, q10
    vrev64.8    q11, q11

    vswp        d19, d16
    vswp        d18, d17
    vswp        d23, d20
    vswp        d22, d21

    vst1.8      {d16, d17, d18, d19}, [pDst], postInc
    vst1.8      {d20, d21, d22, d23}, [pDst], postInc

    bpl     1b
    add     pSrc, pSrc, iLen
    cmp     iLen, #-64
    sub     pDst, pDst, iLen
    bxle    lr      // return
    b       1b
.endfunc
.end
```

- The only registers you have to preserve are: `r4-r11,lr` and `q4-q7`, and ONLY IF you actually have to use them.
- You can return with `bx lr` if you didn't preserve anything and corrupt `lr`
- You can deal with the 'residuals' most efficiently the way I did it ("withholding tax", `bpl`, and `add/sub` by the negative loop counter after the loop).
- You should align the main loop to 32bytes for the I-Cache efficiency.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jake 'Alquimista' Lee
But what I actually want is that, this function should work for every possible array length. Because an image can be various resolutions like 352*288, 52*54 and 78*56   then array length will be 101376, 2808 and 4368. Some of them will not be divisible by 64.

Comment: @RajibTheKing It works for ALL lengths greater than 64. It doesn't have to be a multiple of 64. Look carefully how I dealt with the loop counter inside and outside of the loop.

Comment: I tried to execute this code... 
But it gives me following error..  
TestCamera/Neon_Assembly.s:449:1: error: unknown directive
.func
^
TestCamera/Neon_Assembly.s:481:1: error: unknown directive
.endfunc
^
Would you please solve this for me.

Comment: @RajibTheKing I'm using GCC, and it seems you are probably using Clang.   You can simply remove both `.func` and `.endfunc` since they are solely for profiling purposes. Or you could try to replace them with `.fnstart` and `.fnend` respectively.

Comment: Jake 'Alquimista' LEE,  Thanks a lot for your wonderful contribution. 
I have successfully executed this code portion in apple Ipod 5th generation device. This function is working great and really much time efficient than I expected. 
I have tested this function with an larger image frame(Where array Length is 1280x1280x3 = 4915200) in both ways...... C++ std::reverse() and ARM NEON Assembly(this function)... The result is,  std::reverse() took 47 ms on the other hand.... ARM NEON solution took only 28 ms. That's really great optimization and it's gonna save a lot of time of my process.

Comment: @RajibTheKing I'm glad it worked. I added the cache preloading instruction `pld` after `subs`. Try this one, and if it doesn't bring any performance gain, remove it again. BTW `std::reverse` is much faster than I thought. Apple must have NEON optimized this function as well. I cannot imagine the integer core being capable of pulling off this performance.

Comment: Could the `std::reverse` version use integer byte-swap instructions even if it doesn't use NEON?  I agree there's probably something better than byte-stores, though, so that's cool.  If the NEON version bottlenecks on memory bandwidth for a large image that doesn't fit in cache, there might actually be a bigger difference between versions.

Comment: @PeterCordes ARM doesn't have any byte swap instructions (it has `rev` (byte reverse) though which is better IMO) I think it's possible to write decent performing functions without NEON, PROVIDED the alignments are in line with each other, like the OP's case.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: endian-swap like x86's `bswap` is what I meant.  4B or 8B at a time is not bad.

Comment: You could do a cache-efficient in-place reverse if you load from the start and end, then store to the end and start, and meet in the middle.  (Probably need a prologue to reduce it to aligned chunks or something).  Or start in the middle and work out to the ends, so the front of the array is hot in cache when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I want show respect to **Jake 'Alquimista' LEE** as I have learnt a lot from his answer. Here I am going to share an alternative solution for this problem.

```
.macro NEON_ASM_FUNC_BEGIN
.syntax unified
.text
.extern printf
.align 2
.arm
.globl _$0
_$0:
.endm

.macro NEON_ASM_FUNC_END
mov pc, lr
.endm

NEON_ASM_FUNC_BEGIN Reverse_array_arm_neon
push {r3-r8, lr}
pInData     .req    r0
iLen        .req    r1
pOutData    .req    r2
iOverlap    .req    r3
iTemp       .req    r4

add         pOutData,   pOutData,   iLen
add         pOutData,   pOutData,   #8
ands        iOverlap,   iLen,       #7

beq         loop_Reverse //if(iLen % 8 == 0) goto loop_Reverse

sub         pOutData,   pOutData,   #16
vld1.u8     {d0},       [pInData]!
vrev64.u8   d1,         d0
vst1.u8     {d1},       [pOutData]!
subs        iLen,       iLen,       iOverlap
beq Reverse_array_arm_neon_completed //if(iLen == 0) go to end

mov         iTemp,      #8
sub         iTemp,      iTemp,      iOverlap
sub         pInData,    pInData,    iTemp
add         pOutData,   pOutData,   iTemp

loop_Reverse:
    vld1.u8     {d0},       [pInData]!
    vrev64.u8   d1,         d0
    sub         pOutData,   pOutData, #16
    vst1.u8     {d1},       [pOutData]!
    subs        iLen,        #8
    bne loop_Reverse

Reverse_array_arm_neon_completed:

pop {r3-r8, pc}
NEON_ASM_FUNC_END
```

I have tested this function in Apple **Ipod touch 5th generation**(32bit/Cortex A9/ARMv7-A Platform) device. This function is working for every possible array length. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's probably a lot slower on an in-order ARM, because it doesn't hide the latency of loads or ALU operations with unrolling.  For big arrays, put small-input handling code like this in front of Jake's 64-byte loop.

Comment: I have analyzed these two function with same larger array. These two function took exactly same time.

Comment: I'm saying they might take different times on *other* CPUs.  [Cortex A9 is an out-of-order CPU core](https://developer.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a9), so out-of-order execution is hiding the latency of the load / ALU in each loop iteration, so it doesn't matter that it's not ready when the store executes.  The load + ALU in the next iteration start while the previous iteration's store is still waiting for data on an out-of-order CPU.

Comment: But if you don't care about any other CPUs except specifically that one, then sure, use this loop.  Smaller code-size is an advantage, so unrolling more is bad if you don't need it on the CPU you're tuning for.  (Jake's might help for small arrays when data is hot in L1 cache, though.  This only processes 64 bits at a time.  You could easily do a 128b load, a 128b vrev64.u8, and two 64-bit stores.)

Comment: Thank you for you detail explanation @Peter Cordes , Now I got the whole point.

Comment: @PeterCordes NEON bypasses L1 cache, and on some advanced cores such as the A15, there is a loop buffer that can handle up to 15 instructions. Unrolling it deeper to 128bytes per iteration would make the function disqualify for the loop buffer, resulting in increased power consumption and potentially lower performance. Most of the time, lower power consumption is much more important than a slight gain in performance on ARM.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Ah interesting.  [Apparently having NEON bypass L1 is optional.](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html)  You're implying that's a typical config?  Do 128-bit stores not have better throughput than 64-bit on typical ARM uarches?  i.e. the data path is really only 64 bits wide anyway?  And was I wrong about hiding the latency for in-order cores?  I thought I'd seen other people saying that was a thing on ARM, like it would be on P5 Pentium or Atom.  Or just that in this case it still runs nearly as fast because of HW prefetch?

Comment: BTW, Intel CPUs have a similar loop buffer for already-decoded uops (same sizes as the IDQ that feeds the issue/rename stage, 28 to 64 uops).  It has power and throughput benefits there, too.  (This includes SnB-family and Silvermont / Knight's Landing).  The power benefit doesn't get much attention, especially on big-core (non Atom) CPUs, even though x86 decoders take much more power than ARM.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unlike `x86`, ARM is designed more around power efficiency over perfromance. And you cannot say anything for certain since Cortex-A9. Every chip might be different in cycle timings and default config technically. Especially Apple's chips are quite different, because they  licensed the ISA, not the core architecture. Nevertheless, they are all more or less derived from ARM's reference design, and some common sense will do for optimizations. And you are right about out-of-order stuff, and optimizing for the in-order LITTLE cluster is always preferable.

Comment: @RajibTheKing You shouldn't be deceived by the benchmark numbers. Just like Peter mentioned, the out-of-order engine on Apple's chips will optimize the code in runtime on the fly. In fact, Apple's A series chips are by far the most powerful ones in the mobile sector, and that makes them the worst platforms for learning optimizations.

Comment: @RajibTheKing Get yourself a Nexus S for `aarch32`, and the cheapest Android phone with a Cortex-A53 cluster only for `aarch64`. Raspberry Pi 2/3 will do, too. Nexus S is especially well suited for this purpose since it has very fast memory access(even faster than the Galaxy Nexus), hence you can see the instruction cycle gains more clearly. You can download DS-5 Community Edition for free from ARM's website which is the best assembly editor IMO. https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/ds-5-development-studio/editions/community-edition